# move_uploaded_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error

Tags: php, upload, file-permissions

I keep getting this error when trying to configure the upload directory with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 on CentOS.

In php.ini:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/
```

In httpd.conf:

```
Directory /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/>
    Options  -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/images/>
                Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

CentOS directory permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 11 10:01 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 12 04:54 tmp_file_upload
```

No matter what I do, I keep getting this error from PHP when I upload the file:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/robot.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/mysite/process.php on line 78
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpsKD2Qm' to 'images/robot.jpg' in /var/www/html/mysite/process.php on line 78

As you can see, it never did take the configuration from the php.ini file regarding the upload file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 775? Maybe your server is running as nobody. Only root can write in this case (your "images" permissions)...

Comment: what does it means ? how can i change it ?

Comment: Remember that ALL parent directories also need to have the right permissions.

Comment: just a footnote here from my recent wall banging episode.. remember that sometimes linux can too be fickle. I tried all manner of things and eventually renamed the dest directory and re-created it and it worked just fine. permissions, ownership etc. identical to the old one..

Answer (score 216, accepted):

This is because `images` and `tmp_file_upload` are only writable by `root` user. For upload to work we need to make the owner of those folders same as httpd process owner OR make them globally writable (bad practice).

1. Check apache process owner: `$ps aux | grep httpd`. The first column will be the owner typically it will be `nobody`
2. Change the owner of `images` and `tmp_file_upload` to be become `nobody` or whatever the owner you found in step 1.

   ```
   $sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/images/

   $sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/
   ```
3. Chmod `images` and `tmp_file_upload` now to be writable by the owner, if needed [Seems you already have this in place]. Mentioned in @Dmitry Teplyakov answer.

   ```
   $ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/images/

   $ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/
   ```
4. For more details why this behavior happend, check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir , note that it also talking about `open_basedir` directive.

Comment: This fix applies to situations where you might of changed the servers php type from fast_CGI, CGI to Apache_mod as plesk etc.. can continue with original user's permissions not apache. This fixed my issues.

Comment: I am having this same error but both the process and folders are owned by `jacob` (me as it is my local machine) and the folders all have `755` or `775`.

Comment: I had to restart my apache process `sudo service httpd restart` after changing permissions. Then it worked :) Instead of changing owner `chown` I added my apache process to a 'www' group and added these directories to the same 'www' group through `chgrp`

Answer (score 100):

You can also run this script to find out the Apache process owner:

`<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`

And then change the owner of the destination directory to what you've got. Use the command:

```
chown user destination_dir
```

And then use the command

```
chmod 755 destination_dir
```

to change the destination directory permission.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. I first used Laith Shadeed's method but I don't get same result when typing **ps aux | grep httpd** and `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: **ps aux | grep https** doesn't return web server owner name.
This does : **ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1**

Fron Symfony doc.

Comment: Note that in the above command, there should be two spaces between "-d\" and "-f1". If you copy-paste as-is, you may get an error like "cut: bad delimiter".

Comment: should this be `www-data`? *usually*

Comment: Much better answer than the currently accepted one. exec('whoami'); was a much better solution to finding the user that apache runs as than the currently accepted method of checking apaches process

Comment: Appreciate it, `exec('whoami')` saved me!

Comment: Watch out here, this shows the user that PHP runs under, not the Apache user. If using mod_php these are the same but if, as is now very common, you're using something else (like php_fpm) they can easily be different.

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me.

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
```

Then logout or reboot.

If `SELinux` complains, try the following

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www(/.*)?'
sudo restorecon -Rv '/var/www(/.*)?'
```

Answer (score 27):

If you have Mac OS X, go to the file root or the folder of your website.

Then right-hand click on it, go to get information, go to the very bottom (*Sharing & Permissions*), open that, change all read-only to read and write.  Make sure to open padlock, go to setting icon, and choose *Apply* to the enclosed items...

Comment: Why are you commenting on the Mac OS when his question is about a Linux system?

Comment: @Kmeixner this question about Linux but I had exactly the same issue on my OSX. Thanks for this comment it worked for me after I changed the writing options in the folder `/private/var/tmp` on my Mac.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to add this to the previous suggestions. If you are using a version of Linux that has [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) enabled then you should also execute this in a shell:

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/your/directory
```

Along with giving your web server user permissions either through group or changing of the owner of the directory.

Comment: `restorecon -R -v /path/to/your/directory` probably also needs to be included in this afterwards. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html

Comment: may very well be true, but i was under the assumption that chcon "changed context" ie it was just changed.  what you are looking at uses "semanage fcontext" first which puts it into some settings file "file_contexts.local", however it never changes the context.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks man. This solved my problem. Would you please shed some light on the matter? What does this command actually do? I went over the man pages and even the info for chcon and didn't find the value of the type you entered. I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: it makes the directory or files readable by the web server (httpd)... i honestly dont want to and probably couldnt explain selinux as i barely have an understanding in it myself... please see https://www.nsa.gov/what-we-do/research/selinux/documentation/  and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/index

Answer (score 12):

Change permissions for this folder

`# chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/mysite/images/`

Comment: did it now its like :
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 11 10:01 images
also on :
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 12 04:54 tmp_file_upload
but still the same error

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

1. open /etc/apache2/envvars

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/envvars
   ```
2. replace `www-data` with your `your_username`

   ```
   "export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data"
   ```

   replace with

   ```
   export APACHE_RUN_USER='your_username'
   ```

Comment: And **restart Apache** (`$ sudo service apache2 restart`)to see effects in `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this related issue even after having already successfully run composer. I updated composer, and when running `composer install` or `php composer.phar install` I got:

> ...failed to open stream: Permission denied...

It turns out after much research that the previous answers regarding changing permissions for the folder worked. They are just slightly different directories now.

In my install, on OS X, the cache file is in `/Users/[USER]/.composer/cache`, and I was having trouble because the cache file was owned by root.  Changing ownership of '.composer' recursively to my user solved the issue.

This is what I did:

```
sudo chown -R [USER] cache
```

Then I ran the composer install again and voila!

Answer (score 5):

This problem happens when the apache user (www-data) does not have permission to write in the folder. To solver this problem you need to put the user inside the group www-data.

I just made this:

Execute this php code `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` to discover the user used by apache. After, execute the commands in the terminal:

```
user@machine:/# cd /var/www/html

user@machine:/var/www/html# ls -l
```

It will return something like this:

```
total of files

drwxr-xr-x 7 user group size date folder
```

I kept the user but changed the group to www-data

```
chown -R user:www-data yourprojectfoldername

chmod 775 yourprojectfoldername
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution is so easy. Only right click the IMAGE (destination) folder, go to properties, click the permission tab, and change others access to *Create and delete files*.

Comment: Quickest way BUT, only you are using GUI for FTPing (FileZilla, WinSCP)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the permission of tmp_file_upload to 755
Following is the command
chmod -R 755 tmp_file_upload

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`find /var/www/html/mysite/images/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -v 664`

Comment: getting :
chmod: missing operand after `664'

Answer (score 1):

It happens if `SELinux` is enabled. Disable that in `/etc/selinux/config` by setting `SELINUX=disabled` and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the solutions above, but the following solved my problem

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t your_file_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to change the ownership of the file to '_www' which the Apache user and group.