# Can't make Laravel 4 to work on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying Laravel for the first time after reading an announcement of the Laravel4 beta releasing.

I followed [these steps](http://four.laravel.com/) I installed composer and laravel with all the dependencies it needed. I put the laravel inside my `~/public_html` directory - as I'm used to do it with Codeigniter, but I think something's wrong here.

If I point to the browser to `http://localhost/~carlo/laravel-develop/`, it just displays the content of the directory.

Then, while on the filesystem I had a `laravel-develop/public` folder, it didn't appear on the browser.

I've found that changing the `.htaccess` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

resulted in an error when I try to access the public folder.
The error:

> ErrorException: Warning: file_put_contents(/home/carlo/public_html/laravel-develop/app/config/../storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/carlo/public_html/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php line 77

another one:

> /home/carlo/public_html/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php line 77

then a long list of errors. The last one is:

> require_once('/home/carlo/public_html/laravel-develop/start.php') in /home/carlo/public_html/laravel-develop/public/index.php line 53

Comment: You should probably use Laravel 3 if you are starting out.

Comment: Same problem here. Unfortunately, none of the answers here helped. I'm positive that my permissions are set correctly, as well as the .htaccess is fine. Still, can't make it work.

Comment: @dualed that's not a really good suggestion... IMHO better learn L4, for sure

Comment: @Gadoma that was in january, when Laravel 4 was in pre-beta phase.

Answer (score 70):

Try to change the folder permissions for the `storage` folder using the terminal:

`chmod -R 777 storage`

More info on this matter can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/install#installation).

Comment: Mark this answer as correct if it helped. This worked for me multiple times.

Comment: That worked for me too... But why can't I set set the group of storage to www-data and its permissions to 775?

Comment: Actually, `chmod 757` is enough. Using `777` might be a little over the top.

Comment: @enchance Sure? I just tried with `chmod 757` and it did not work. It did with `chmod 777`.

Comment: chmod -R 775 would be a more secure solution. In this case the group of storage folder should be the same as the web server's.

Comment: `775` only worked for me after I did `sudo chown -R _www:_www mywebfolder` .. see my answer below.

Comment: chown on storage worked for me, ubuntu 14.04 and laravel

Answer (score 16):

Your errors resulted because laravel couldn't write to the app/storage folder. The rest was just a stack trace. In order to make the storage folder writable, cd into your app folder and then run:

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of permissions since when I point the browser to `http://localhost/~carlo/laravel-develop/` the `public` directory doesn't even appear in the directory tree. I changed the permissions anyway, as you suggested, but it didn't work.

Comment: Then you probably put that .htaccess in the root folder, which is why it's not displaying the public folder... .htaccess goes in the public directory.

Comment: 755 won't make the directory writable for the web server as you have RWX RX RX but you need RWX on each so `chmod -R 777 storage`

Answer (score 11):

**Production way**, moderate complexity for people not familiar with Unix, but more **secure**:

1. Go in super user mode (sudo -s or su).
2. Create group `web` (`groupadd web`)
3. Add you main user to group `web` (suppose your user is `cool_user`, so run `usermod -a -G web cool_user`)
4. Add php-fpm or web server user (if php is used as a SAPI module) to `web` group (for example, on CentOS php-fpm utilize `apache` user name, so in most cases this will work: `usermod -a -G web apache`)
5. Change your project root directory group owner to `web` recursively (`chgrp -R web /path/to/project/root/`)
6. Grant recursively write permission for group (`chmod -R g+w /path/to/project/root/`
7. *Optionally* To allow all newly created by `apache` (or some other) user files and folders be accessible from your user, make them receive group ownership same as their parent folder by setting *groupid* bit recursively on your project root directory (`chmod -R g+s /path/to/project/root/`).

Voila!.

**Fast and dirty way**, for those who doesn't care about security and want make it works at any cost, **not secure**:

1. Go in super user mode (sudo -s or su).
2. Grant recursively full permission (read, write, execute) for all users (`chmod -R o=rwx /path/to/project/root/`

Answer (score 5):

In my case I resolved this error by modifying in file /app/config/app.php the default setting:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

to my local custom virtualhost host url:

```
'url' => 'http://mydomain.local',
```

This seemed to be THE essential change that resolved the issue (I also chmod'ed the storage folder, as suggested here)

hope this helps some of you..

Answer (score 3):

further to above, if you're using a virtualbox/vagrant VM type environment, then on my Mac I needed to issue the chmod on the host (mac) system but on my Windows box, it was fine issuing the chmod direcly on the VM.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add: Options +FollowSymLinks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: now it just gives me a 500 error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the installation documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration

Pay attention to the bit here:

```
Laravel requires one set of permissions to be configured - folders within app/storage require write access by the web server.
```

There is also other stuff thats useful in that document, so make sure you read it all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, here is how I solve it:
In your httpd-vhosts.conf files you need to add the configurations to your folders, this is what I have in mine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your@mail.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/carlospublic_html"
    ServerName carlos.local
    <Directory "/home/carlos/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The webroot of your server should point to the `/public` folder of your Laravel installation. This is where the `index.html` file recides from where Laravel is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

First, [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after) will help you with permissions.  Second, you may need to add `RewriteBase ~/carlo/public_html/laravel-develop` to your .htaccess since you're running it out of a home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got this error too and changing the write permissions didn't seem to work either. It turned out I needed to change the User and Group settings in apache's httpd.conf file. Here's a good tutorial for it: [Enable Write Permissions for the Native Built-In Apache in Mac OS X Lion](http://paulmason.name/item/change-apache-user-group-in-lion-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Checking on the Requirement for the LR4, your local server must have these:
PHP >= 5.3.7
MCrypt PHP Extension

Otherwise, will fail. I am facing this trouble also and now looking for an updated PHP and its extension for my XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I like this method better than changing permissions to 777.
Set Apache to run as you.

1. In terminal type `id` to get `uid=123(Myname)`.
2. Open /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and edit it to use your username.

   ```
   <IfModule unixd_module>
      User Myname
      Group staff
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Back to terminal: `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem a few minutes back and using sudo chmod -R 777 storage seemed to help make the storage/meta/services.json writable. Just to add to what everyone has been saying. This worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, Dammy. However, if the other answers helped you, there's no need to post a duplicate - just upvote!