# services.json failed to open stream: Permission denied in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was playing around with a working Laravel 4 installation and moved everything into a sub folder. Then I decided to not do that and I moved it all back (all via the command line):

```
mv * /folder
```

and then

```
cd folder
mv * ../
```

Now, the site is throwing the following error:

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/quantquote/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Here is a screenshot of the full error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8uTM.png

I've already tried setting  permissions on the /storage folder to 777 to no avail.

Comment: `chmod -R 0777 app/storage` should be good...

Comment: Tried that again, and it's had no effect :(

Comment: Try running both `find app/storage -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;` and `find app/storage -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

Comment: @CollinHenderson that did it, thanks. can you explain what this did?

Comment: Those commands changed the permission of all directories and files under `app/storage` to `777`.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo is correct. I'm going to copy this to a proper answer if you'd like to accept it.

Comment: Forgive my naivete, but shouldn't we avoid giving everyone read, write, and execute privileges to this directory? Does the user that needs access to this location depend on the owner of the php program?

Comment: setting the folder permissions to 777 can cause security issues. Please consider changing it to 775 instead, preventing giving write access to others.

Comment: This post is the correct answer to your question 

[Permission denied in Laravel 4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345174/cant-make-laravel-4-to-work-on-localhost

Answer (score 29):

Spent a whole day for solving this and this command simply solved my problem.

If your permissions are 777 for Laravel App folder and you still get this error, it's because [SEliux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) has blocked it. You can easily unblock your application's folder using this command:

`su -c "chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /usr/share/nginx/YOUR_LARAVEL_APP/"`

That's it!

BTW never disable SElinux: http://stopdisablingselinux.com/

Comment: thanks so much! I'd like to add that my command ended up being `chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/laravel` since I am on a local machine running as root already, in case anyone else is vaguely sleep deprived and not reading things correctly.  Again, thanks!

Comment: This is the answer to so many questions with Laravel and logging. Thanks for that. Saved another day of debugging

Answer (score 23):

As I stated in my comment:

`find app/storage -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

`find app/storage -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

This will chmod all directories and files in `app/storage` to 777.

Comment: I would set the permissions to 775 instead of 777 and configure the file ownerships and groups accordingly. i.e. the group of the web server and the app/storage folder will be the same.

Comment: As a security precaution, I'd recommend `chmod -R ug+rwX,o-rwx .` This will set directories only to execute, and prevent people outside of the group doing horrible things to your files.

Comment: To read how to set your directory permissions in the right way check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/987864

Answer (score 11):

As the problem is related to *permissions* try re-giving the right permissions to `app/storage` and all its sub-directories and file.

You can do so from the root path of your Laravel app typing:

```
chmod -Rvc 777 app/storage
```

If for some reason this doesn't work, try:

```
find app/storage -type d -exec chmod -vc 777 {} \;
find app/storage -type f -exec chmod -vc 777 {} \;
```

Comment: _Please, if you will downvote this answer then also provide any explanation so we can improve it._ Thanks.

Comment: Downvote: never use chmod 777 ! Suggesting such a dangerous command as a solution should be banned from SO.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. what would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 8):

When chmod 777 or chmod 775 fails check that subdirectories really exists:

```
app/storage/
├── cache
├── logs
├── meta
├── sessions
└── views
```

in case these folders does not exists you must to create it:

```
cd app/storage/
mkdir meta logs cache sessions views
cd ../
find storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find storage -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

UPDATE 2016 for laravel 5+

In a default Laravel 5+ application structure, `storage` is at the same level than `app`. So the previous command becomes:

```
cd storage/
mkdir meta logs cache sessions views
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure

Comment: This answer helped me, I needed to create the folder structure under the storage folder. But in my case (for Laravel 5.0) the views, sessions and cache folders had to be in a subfolder named "framework".

Answer (score 7):

If you're using CentOS7, follows these steps:

1. Change app/storage directory ownership

   ```
   chown apache:apache app/storage
   ```
2. Change app/storage permissions

   ```
   chmod -R 775 app/storage
   ```
3. Prevent SELinux from blocking the app/storage directory

   ```
   su -c "chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t [fullpath]/app/storage"
   ```

Answer (score 6):

just type this on terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 5):

Never run a 777, in recursive mode. It's a security issue.
For now, remove the services.json file, and try this :

[Laravel 4: Failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied/22192814#22192814)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts from the link, if the link dies, then the answer will not be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands one by one:

```
setenforce 0
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

Comment: Why there is no up vote for this one? This works like a charm! :D thanks!

Comment: Because it is disabling SELinux, instead of learning how to use it, which is dangerous advice. Additionally, the poster hasn't actually explained what this 'solution' is doing.