# hosting an mvc app within vagrant

Tags: networking, laravel-4, apache2, vagrant

Maybe it's just because it's a Friday and it's after closing time but I've been stuck on this for an hour and can't quite get it working. I'm using Vagrant with an application we're building - the git repo contains the `Vagrantfile` and a Laravel application. We have `/deploy`, `/tests`, and `/src` directories; the actual Laravel framework lives in `/src`. On my local machine, I have set up a VirtualHost that let's me access the application by browsing to `localhost:9000`:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "/Application/mamp/apache2/htdocs/myapp/src/public"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/Application/mamp/apache2/htdocs/myapp/src/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Works like a charm. So I copied the relevant bits to my Vagrant setup:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/src/public"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/var/www/src/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My `Vagrantfile` looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/main.sh"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.101", virtualbox__intnet: true
end
```

And my `vagrant/main.sh` file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update

echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password notthepassword | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password notthepassword | debconf-set-selections

apt-get install -y mysql-common mysql-server mysql-client

apt-get install -y apache2

apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5
apt-get install -y php5-mysql php5-curl php-pear php5-imagick php5-mcrypt php5-memcache

apt-get install -y vim

a2enmod rewrite
sed -i -e 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
cp /vagrant/vagrant/bgs /etc/apache2/sites-available
a2ensite bgs
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
```

Once it's all up and running I can ping `192.168.100.101`. But it's not serving any HTML - if I browse to that address in Chrome, I get a "no data received" error. If I go to `192.168.100.101:8081` Chrome says it can't find the address. How can I configure everything to play nice together and let me clone my repo, run `vagrant up`, and browse to `192.168.100.101:8081` and see my app?

(Also: I even added a port forwarding line in there to go from `guest:8081` to `host:8081`. That generated an HTTP 500 error ("The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."). Not sure if that's progress or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a number of things happening all at once:

- I was using Ubuntu 12 LTS, which had a version of PHP a little to old to run the edge release of Laravel. Installing an upgraded version of PHP fixed that.
- The `virtualbox__intnet` directive was...wrong. Somehow. Changed that whole `Vagrantfile` line to: `config.vm.network "private_network", :ip => "192.168.100.101", :auto_network => true`
- The different ports, mucking about in the various symlinked directories vs. apache config directories...needlessly complicated.

Here's my final setup, in case anyone else has this exact, specific problem:

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/ubuntu-13.10-64-puppet"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/main.sh"
    config.vm.network "private_network", :ip => "192.168.100.101", :auto_network => true
end
```

main.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update

echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password f6b6rWixbu99CtQ | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password f6b6rWixbu99CtQ | debconf-set-selections

apt-get install -y mysql-common mysql-server mysql-client apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php-pear php5-imagick php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-json

a2enmod rewrite
sed -i -e 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
cp /vagrant/vagrant/app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
a2ensite app.conf

#fix for ubuntu 13.10: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10
ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
php5enmod mcrypt
#/fix

#json licensing snafu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode
php5enmod json
#/snafu

#may need to be done on the host OS, not the guest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954625/services-json-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in-laravel-4
chmod -R 0777 /vagrant/src/app/storage

rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /vagrant/src/public /var/www

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Apache site configuration copied in:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/var/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(BTW, though this config looks very similar to the default apache configuration, I found it was easier and more extensible to create a config for whatever project I happen to be working on, and if I need to expand on the options for a future project, I can.)