# Laravel permission denied in storage/meta/services.json

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, fedora

Well, this error is so know but in my case I could not mitigate it in my side. I have migrated a laravel-4 installation to another server and for the first time accessed I get this error:

> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/MyApp/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have followed different googled aswers as below

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971549/1424329
- [Can't make Laravel 4 to work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345174/cant-make-laravel-4-to-work-on-localhost)
- http://laravel.io/forum/05-08-2014-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied
- [Laravel 4: Failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

However, any of them could not fix my problem. I also tried cleaning the cache and dump autoclass command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 app/storage
composer dump-autoload
```

Also, I have thought that the webserver process might be considered in the problem, so I seek for its user like this:

```
$ ps -ef|grep httpd

apache   11978 11976  0 11:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Then, I added `apache` to the directory group owner and the problems persists.

I do not know what else to do, I am going insane because dancing naked under full moon neither fixed the problem.

Comment: That sounds terribly annoying. Have you also tried ``php artisan dump-autoload``, and not just ``composer dump-autoload``?

Comment: In my desesperate moment I have changed native OS config files and at this moment the system can not start..  (I am publishing this from the mobile)

Comment: Oh, damn... good luck with that. :/

Comment: @JoelHinz, I came back since I followed [this bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22279001/1424329). Roll back and continue with this laravel problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have discovered the cause of this problem. Looks like `selinux` does not allow to httpd service (apache web server) write in my app folder. So, I did:

```
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Now everthing is working fine!

Comment: Yay! Glad you found the problem! :)

Comment: It's time to drink a beer

Comment: @Moak,  I am not an Linux expert. In my case, my environment is a Fedora 20 linux distribution that comes with a security application/demon named "selinux".  So,  the command above is telling something like: "please selinux,  lets apache webserver write content in my application folder"

Answer (score 2):

Happens to me some times, but I just delete it and Laravel recreates it. As far as I know, this is just a cache list of services and can be safely removed.

Comment: Let me try this, it has sence.