# SessionHandler::read(): open PATH failed: Permission denied (13) in laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, laravel

I just uploaded a laravel app I have been working on to my server which is ubuntu, the server is apache.  Everything is set up correctly accept for the file permissions resulting in the error in the title.

I set the directory the app is in to 777 but that has not helped so I am wondering what else I should change.

Also is there are standard 'secure' permissions setting for directories and files running a web app like this?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345174/cant-make-laravel-4-to-work-on-localhost). The directory of interest is *storage*. That's the only folder Laravel needs write permissions to (I think).