# Laravel 4 not working on apache2 localhost

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, localhost

I've followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345174/cant-make-laravel-4-to-work-on-localhost) but it's still not working for me.

I have PHP 5.4.26 and mcrypt installed and enabled. I have given 777 permissions to the app/storage folder.

I uploaded my laravel installation (which was working inside another folder, using the built-in laravel development server) to `www/laravel/`. When I visit `localhost/laravel` it gives the laravel root directory listing, rather than running the application.

If I visit `localhost/laravel/public` I just get a blank page.

Can anyone help me to get apache to run the `public/index.php` file?

Comment: Check your apache2 error log, which by default is in /var/log/apache2/error.log - also make sure you gave the permissions to app/storage recursively (`chmod -R ...`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `DocumentRoot` directive in your httpd.conf file to point to `www/laravel` instead of just `www`