# Trying make file upload with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying make a file upload using PHP. To do it I'm using $_FILE but I can't understand why does not works. Looking for solutions I'm found some suggestion to use $_FILE, but still can't do this works. To I see if upload works I'm using Postman of Chrome. I'm using Ubuntu with LAMP.

How could I do it ?

```
<?php

$arquivo = isset($_FILES["file"]) ? $_FILES["file"] : FALSE;

if(!$arquivo) { 
    echo "You can not access this file directly!"; 
}else{
    $diretorio = "/home/fernando/Imagens/";

    if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo["tmp_name"], $diretorio.$arquivo["name"])) { 
            echo "File upload ok!"; 
    }else{
         echo "File not upload!"; 
    }   
}

?>
```

**Exception**

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(/home/fernando/Imagens/avatar_empresa.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
<b>/var/www/TelefonesUteis/ws/add_file.php</b> on line 
<b>12</b>
<br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpq9AlVw' to '/home/fernando/Imagens/avatar_empresa.jpg' in 
<b>/var/www/TelefonesUteis/ws/add_file.php</b> on line 
<b>12</b>
<br />
```

**Postman**

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors in your logs?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also post the HTML form please

Comment: I bet the enctype is missing,also since you are on Linux check permissions

Comment: I'm trying use this PHP to send image to WebService using Volley with Multipart

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582507/move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-and-permission-denied-error `chmod 777 /home/fernando/Imagens/`

Comment: Maan the error is very clear if you read it.. there are no enough write permissions on the path to which you are trying to move the file to.. give it write permissions and try again

Comment: very nice. Thanks a lot !!! I did `chmod -R 777 /home/fernando/Imagens` and now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script doesn't have permissions to add and/or execute files in `/home/fernando/Imagens/`. Your will have to use `chmod`:

`chmod -R 775 /home/fernando/Imagens`

Comment: `775` should be enough, don't need to execute anything there surely?

Comment: Yes, you are correct `775` is probably a safer alternative in most cases. Edited my answer.

Comment: Remember that CHMOD only gives permissions to  the current files there, if you're gonna add new folders/files they will be blocked by default, you would have to repeat the chmod thing each time your application uploads or generates a new thing inside that folder.
Dealing with web applications on Linux (that make use of uploads or file management) is a HEADACHE, enough said hahaha, get ready to use a lot of console.

Comment: Yes, but his problem is that he doesn't have permissions to write files to the folder. If he use chmod 775 or 777, he will have those permissions.