# Permissions - Error on move uploaded file

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

So i'm receiving a warning on uploading an image:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/photo.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied..

Here is the code:

```
$upload = "images/";
$tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$upload/$name");
```

Now if I go to the images directory in putty and type ls -la I get:

```
drwxrwxrwx+ user daemon 96 Apr 16 12:41 .
drwxrwxrwx+ user daemon 96 Apr 16 12:41 ..
```

Not entirely sure what this means, I assume I have read write execute permissions.

I tried chmod 0777 but I still receive the error.

Can anyone tell me how I can upload the images without the permissions error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [move\_uploaded\_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied " error after all configurations i did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after)

Comment: I've tried everything in this question suggestion.. and nothing worked, so I posted this one.

Answer (score 1):

Give permission to the folder

```
   $upload = "images/";
   $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
   $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$upload/$name", 0777);
```

Comment: Although 0777, might be a little to generous security wise :/

Comment: I get an error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0777'.