# Codeigniter failed to open stream permission when upload images

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, jpeg

Code:

```
$filename = '12345.jpeg';
$source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData); 
$imageSave = imagejpeg($source,$filename,100); 
imagedestroy($source);
$this->ftp->connect();
$this->ftp->upload($imageSave,'/public_ftp/incoming/'.$filename,'ascii', 0775); 
$this->ftp->close();
```

Error:
**Codeigniter failed to open stream permission when upload images.**

Comment: did you check the permissions on **incoming** folder?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a permissions issue. Try this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 path/to/public_ftp/incoming/
```

However, this will give permission to everyone. For localhost this is ok. But for production environment you should do it in another way. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after#answer-8104498) for more info

@edit

If you are getting this error when trying to upload a file from a form. **codeigniter** [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

> **The Upload Folder**
>
> You'll need a destination folder for your uploaded images. Create a
>   folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called **uploads** and
>   set its file permissions to 777.

Do you have this folder with permissions set to 777?

Comment: Thank you. I set the premission 777 in GUI to incoming folder but the problem has not be solved. Why?

Comment: You are getting the error when you are trying to upload this file to the ftp, or when you are trying to upload a file which are being received through a form?

Comment: First one. Thanks. I pass the base64 string to the php side. $imageData is a base64 string. You mean that I need to save the image in local host first?

Comment: No.. I don't think that is the problem, since you are getting a **permissions** error. You could try it anyway.

Comment: The destination to FTP and CI are different. It will be the problem?

Comment: What you mean by different destination? Did you checked if the permissions are really 777? How did you set this, via `$this->ftp->chmod()`?