# convert base64 data to image and save in codeIgniter folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to convert data url to image and save it in codeigniter folder

```
 private function _convertToImg($data){ //$data is the data url
        $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data);

        $decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
   file_put_contents('/../../uploads/newImage.JPG',$decoded);
}
```

but it resulting an error

> Message:  file_put_contents(/../../uploads/newImage.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

i dont know why this happening, i am not much familiar with php and codeigniter

thank you in advance!

Comment: Problem is your destination folder path.

Comment: Where is your upload folder? inside application?

Comment: I "guess" `file_put_contents('../../uploads/newImage.JPG',$decoded);` is what you are trying to do.

Comment: myProject/uplods, uploads folder contains in same directory of application folder

Answer (score 4):

If application and upload folder in same directory then,

You should write below line as:-

```
// APPPATH will give you application folder path
file_put_contents(APPPATH . '../uploads/newImage.JPG',$decoded);
```

You can also set upload path,

```
$this->upload_config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . '../uploads/';
```

get full information write below lines

```
 $data = $this->upload->data();
 // $data will contain full inforation
 echo "Full path is:". $data['full_path'];
```

This [link](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/) will be useful to you.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: but now seems an error  ,Message:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/portfolioApis/application/../uploads/newImage.JPG): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Give permission to your upload folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570987/codeigniter-failed-to-open-stream-permission-when-upload-images