# image file is not uploading in php

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am just learning php the way it works and trying to upload the file using `move_uploaded_file`. The code i have written seems perfect but at the end it is generating a warning message. I am giving my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['create'])){
$productcatid=$_POST['productcategory'];

$name = ucfirst(trim($_POST['itemname']));
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
$status = true;
}
else{
$status = false;
}
if(isset($_POST['availability'])){
$avalability = true;
}
else{
$avalability = false;
}


$c=$_POST['price'];
$d=$_POST['type'];
$e=$_POST['brandname'];
$f=$_POST['datecreated'];
$g=$_POST['size'];
$h=$_POST['colour'];
$i=$_POST['fabric'];


if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
    $file = $_FILES['upload'];
    $n = $file['name'];
    $s = $file['size'];
    $tm = $file['tmp_name'];
    $er = $file['error'];
    $target = 'uploadedfiles/'.$n;

    if(move_uploaded_file($tm, $target)){
        $sql = "insert into product_items(item_name, is_active, category_id, image_url, date_created, is_item_available, type, brand_name, fabric, size, colour,price) ";
        $sql .= " values('".$name."','".$status."','".$productcatid."','".$upload."','".$f."','".$avalability."','".$d."','".$e."','".$i."','".$g."','".$h."','".$c."')";
        include('config.php');
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        if($res){
          //header('Location:allproductitemcategory.php');
          echo 'success';
        }
        else{
          echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'error uploading file. '.$er;
    }
}


}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

It is giving a following warning

Warning: `move_uploaded_file(uploadedfiles/s3.jpg)` failed to open stream: Permission denied in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/onlineshopping/insertproductitems.php` on line 38

Warning: `move_uploaded_file()`: Unable to move `'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php6TeZrH'` to `'uploadedfiles/s3.jpg'` in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/onlineshopping/insertproductitems.php` on line 38
error uploading file. 0

I am just stuck here as I am not able to get it. Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your problem is about permission just chmod (change mode) your folder.
chmod("yourfolder", "r");

Comment: i just changed the permissions of folders where the image was placed and where its to be upload