# Laravel 5 DOMPDF imagepng(.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, file-permissions, dompdf, laravel-5

I am using [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to generate pdf.

Here is my pdf.blade.php:

```
<img src="{{ public_path() . '/images/logo.png' }}" id="logo" />
<table class="order_confirmation"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Company name</th>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <td>test@email.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public function pdf() {
    $data = array();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data);
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Here is error:

> ErrorException in class.pdf.php line 4036: imagepng(.png): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied

And a stacktrace:

> in class.pdf.php line 4036 at HandleExceptions->handleError('2',
>   'imagepng(.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied',
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blablacompany/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php',
>   '4036', array('file' =>
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blablacompany/public/images/logo.png',
>   'x' => '34.015748031496', 'y' => '606.8742519685', 'w' => '334.5', 'h'
>   => '201', 'byte' => '6', 'img' => 'Resource id #278', 'eight_bit' => false, 'wpx' => '446', 'hpx' => '268', 'tempfile_alpha' => '.png',
>   'tempfile_plain' => '.png', 'imgalpha' => resource, 'c' => '256',
>   'allocated_colors' => array('000' => '0', '9598261', '12756008',
>   '9993266', '15848487', '7493443', '12690472', '16309032', '14269479',
>   '5586004', '11637804', '16243240', '8809018', '2169210', '12624680',
>   '15256615', '6638155', '2366072', '5454677', '10256177', '13151271'...

Could you please help me?

P.S.

1. I have tried also url('/images/logo.png') instead of public_path() . '/images/logo.png'
2. I have chmod 777 on storage, vendors and also on public/images, but still not working...

> ErrorException in image_cache.cls.php line 105: file_put_contents():
>   Filename cannot be empty

UPDATE:

- if I set chmod 754 and `return view('pdf')` -> image is not shown (as well as on other pages which are using images/
- if I set chmod 754 and `$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data); return $pdf->stream();` -> PDF is generated but image is stroked square
- but if I set chmod 755 and `return view('pdf')` -> images is shown, but..
- when I try `$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data); return $pdf->stream();` I receive an error message:

> ErrorException in image_cache.cls.php line 105: file_put_contents():
>   Filename cannot be empty

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what I have done, why it's working like that, maybe someone could explain: MacBook-Air:public myuser$ sudo chmod -R 777 images/ - not working
MacBook-Air:public myuser$ sudo chmod -R 755 images/ - not working
MacBook-Air:public myuser$ sudo chmod -R 754 images/ - WORKING . Now at least pdf is generated but images looks like stroked square.. but this is probably another issue

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to deal with it:

1. for pdf generation you should use public_path() instead of url('') (e.g. `<img src="{{ public_path() . '/images/somepicture.jpg' }}" id="logo" />`),
2. `public_path()` won't work if want to load view `return view('yourview');`
3. Use only **.jpg**, .png won't work
4. chmod 755 your image folder

Comment: The `chmod` options seems like an odd requirement and is probably related to your configuration. If you don't have the GD PHP extension enabled you'll have problems with certain image formats. I don't know about the path options, it really depends on what value that returns, but I'm guessing `PDF::loadView()` uses the `load_html()` method of dompdf so all paths are relative on the filesystem.