# PHP - Issue with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload

I've used move_uploaded_file successfully in the past, however I'm having an issue with permissions I believe with a new server I'm testing this on. I've created a folder named "uploads" for the uploads to be moved to via FTP. Here's a screenshot showing the permissions:

[image]

Everyone has read/write access, but when I upload a file I'm getting an error on the line that moves the file to the "uploads" directory:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory.$uploadedFile)) {
```

The file is not moved to the "uploads" folder and looking at the server log I can see entries like this:

php[1344]
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/2.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\test_upload\index.php on line 206
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php2D93.tmp' to 'uploads/2.jpg' in C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\ test_upload\index.php on line 206

I can't see how it can be a permissions issue if all users have read/write/execute on the "uploads" folder? Here are the variables:

$upload_directory='uploads/';
$uploadedFile= $_FILES['photo1']['name'];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move\_uploaded\_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied " error after all configurations i did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after)

Comment: Can you please display all variables? :)

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic I've updated with the variables and full PHP error log entries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `uploads/2.jpg` is `$_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name']` and should therefore have been uploaded to the server's `/tmp/` directory. On most systems, because `/tmp` is a system dir, it has restricted permissions on it.

See if you can alter the perms on `/tmp` or find out exactly *which* dir the tmp uploaded file is being moved to first, before being "uploaded" (and then alter the perms on *that* dir).

Regardless, the path to the file as passed to `move_uploaded_file()` doesn't look right. It needs to be a full-path. Possibly the server-error you're seeing is not happening at *precisely* the same time as the upload operation takes place.

Comment: Sorry my PHP errors didn't paste in correctly - have updated. As you can see the file is uploaded correctly, e.g. C:\Windows\Temp\php2D93.tmp, it just can't move to the uploads folder.

Comment: Yeah but PHP needs to be able to read the source file: `C:\Windows\Temp\php2D93.tmp` so I'd check the webserver running PHP has permission to read _that_ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix this via FTP settings. I had to adjust the settings by logging in to the Windows Server and changing the security settings on the folder I was trying to move files into so that the "Users" had read/write access.