# imagejpeg() permission denied

Tags: php, permissions

```
imagejpeg(/home/gratuco/public_html/users/losabrigosproperties/propertyimages/117_36695_94556965.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/grataden/public_html/clients/addproperties_images.php on line 228
```

There are two sites on the server. I want to upload from one site to the other. What permissions/settings should I give to other directory?

Any solution will help. Thanks.

Comment: change permission to 777

Comment: Don't you need quotes around the string?

Comment: I tried permission to 777. It didnt work. The value is coming from variables

Comment: try `chmod +x yourfile`

Comment: I am uploading the file. How should I use this command with file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a file in a different vhost (`/home/gratuco/`) than the one in which your script is (`/home/grataden/`). Are you sure you have the rights to do this ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to create in different vhost. Can you please elaborate about rights?

Comment: maybe this will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani This didnt work.

Comment: @roberto06 Your statement helped me a lot Thanks.