# webrivers - i cannot upload image in server?

Tags: php

Please help image cannot upload in server, my
php code:-

```
    $gallery_image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "../extra_images/$gallery_image");
```

my error is:-

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(../extra_images/brand-04.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in G:\PleskVhosts\luisant.in\vethathirimaharishischool.org\admin\gallery.php on line 129
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php4118.tmp' to '../extra_images/brand-04.jpg' in G:\PleskVhosts\luisant.in\vethathirimaharishischool.org\admin\gallery.php on line 129
```

Comment: `Permission denied in G:\PleskVhosts\luisant.in\vethathirimaharishischool.org\admin\gallery.php on line 129`

do you have permission to write the tmp folder?

Comment: Error clearly shows that there is permission issue

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand.,

Comment: how to fix this error

Comment: @ThiyagarajanR - login to FTP. find folder extra_images. right click and change permission to 777.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory:

```
failed to open stream: Permission denied on "../extra_images/"
```

you don't have the write permission on the above listed directory. Provide the write permission and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have permission to the directory.

To change the owner and permission of the destination directory which is `/extra_images`

Try this command:

1. `chown user /extra_images`
2. `chmod 755 /extra_images`

Answer (score 0):

This is because images and tmp_file_upload are only writable by root user. For upload to work we need to make the owner of those folders same as httpd process owner OR make them globally writable..[learn more>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after)