# My image isn't being saved in the folder?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an add form, where users can add an image, once they click submit I want the image to be saved into a certain folder located called Event_images (which I use to display the image on another page where I display the image along with other details they inputted. But once I submit the form, the image goes to the MYSQL database, but isn't in the folder where I direct it to. My code and a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/050tf.png) are provided. I want the image to be displayed in the Event_images folder I have created. Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php 

  $event_img = $_FILES['event_img']['name'];

$tempimage = $_FILES['event_img']['tempname'];
move_uploaded_file($tempimage,"Event_images/$event_img");

 ?>
```

The screenshot I have provided is what happens when I try to display the information (because nothing is in the folder which I direct to)

Comment: Maybe your paths are just wrong ... did you tried using absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

`['tempname']` isn't an index of `$_FILES`. [See here.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Use `$tempimage = $_FILES['event_img']['tmp_name'];` instead. I tested locally and it worked fine. If you're using PHP 7 you may need to use `{ }` around `$event_img` when you move the file so it'll process that variable.

Comment: <?php 

  $event_img = $_FILES['event_img']['name'];

$tempimage = $_FILES['event_img']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempimage,"Event_images/{$event_img}");

 ?> would this be the correct syntax?

Comment: @NaeemDogar Bingo!

Comment: Thank you but still nothing is happening, could it be my path? The Event_images folder is located in htdocs/Admin_area/Event_images, but even when I set this as the path it doesn't save?

Comment: Did it generate an `error_log` on your server? You might not have proper permissions to move the file (Just dealt with this exact issue with moving an image the other day).

Comment: It came up with no error, simply just refreshed the webpage as expected, but with no image being saved, do you know how I could gain permission or check if I have permission? Thank you:)

Comment: @NaeemDogar `images` and `tmp_file_upload` are only writable by the root user, and the script you're executing is being processed by httpd, check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8104498/8411905).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$event_img = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['event_img']['name']; 
   $tempimage = $_FILES['event_img']['temp_name']; 
    $folder="Event_images/";
      move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$event_img);
```