# PHP Codeigniter Error: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\phonoblog\system\core): failed
to open stream: Permission denied in
C:\xampp\htdocs\phonoblog\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 80

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
'C:\xampp\htdocs\phonoblog\system\core/'
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
C:\xampp\htdocs\phonoblog\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 80
```

Comment: you need to change folder permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move\_uploaded\_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied " error after all configurations I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after)

Comment: When asking question, please make sure, you add proper formatting, also your title is very generic, please use a more specific title

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7 try this

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `system` & `application` folder has `0775` permission.