# move_uploaded_file(/Advanced Java Programming.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, permission-denied

So, I am working on a system where people working in a company can upload files to a system which will be sorted by departments. I have managed to get the files info(name, size, type), but the problem occurs while trying to upload the file.

I get:

> move_uploaded_file(/Advanced Java Programming.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php1B99.tmp' to '/Advanced Java Programming.pdf'

I have set the permissions of the folder where the file needs to be uploaded to everybody (777).
Here's my code

```
<?php

$department = $_POST['department'];
$file = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

echo "<b>Department: </b>" . $department . "<br>";
echo "<b>Name: </b>" . $file['name']. "<br>";
echo "<b>Size: </b>" . $file['size'] . " bytes<br>";
echo "<b>Type: </b>" . $file['type'];

move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "/". $file['name']);
```

?>

Comment: Possible duplication : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an absolute path for your destination or at least start it with the DIR-constant, "/" ist not a valid (Windows)-path.
Also think about using the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR as "/" is a *nix-standard, but as you're running on Windows, it should be "\" - using the constant will hold the right slash for every system.