# APACHE Permissions are all set but still don't have permission

Tags: php, html, apache, permissions, php-ziparchive

I recently faced this issue, as you can see in the picture, I granted all sorts of permissions to all files, but still I get this error.

Here's the code:

```
$zipdir=dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/tmp';
$zipname="$zipdir/$input[user]-".time().'.zip';
list($pdf,$pdfname)=test_pdf($request);
$zip=new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($zipname,ZipArchive::CREATE)!==true) return $error='Could not open zip archive for writing';
$zip->addFromString("pdf/$pdfname", $pdf->Output('','S'));
$zip->addFile("test-docs/",$testformname);
$zip->close();
if (!file_exists($zipname)) return $error='Could not create zip archive';
```

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmxUg.png

And here's the log:

```
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test/app/test.php
```

Comment: You’ll need to post a short, self-contained example that causes this problem. The error message is pointing potentially not to the zip file, but a temporary folder where it is initially being created, too.

Comment: Umm, I thought it's pointing to Create, Thanks for the mention. but also i had this problem weeks ago i forgot to say and it just got fixed by itself i couldn't find the solution tho.

Comment: Thanks @LilRupert, so is this resolved and we can close it then?

Comment: No, i just faced it again, but this time it seems that it doesn't want to get fixed... im really confused about that. i read on some websites and they couldn't find any solution neither... that's because of my poor english knowledge that i forgot to say "Again" in my comment above.

Comment: Can you please post a small code sample, ideally 5 to 10 lines, that causes that exception to be thrown for you?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if it took time, i was preparing. Question Updated.

Comment: Thanks! Inspect the contents of `$zipname` using `var_dump` or similar. Try skipping ZIP and just use normal file system methods, for instance, `touch` or even better, `is_writable`.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Haas, i'll work on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem just solved!

I needed to grant 775 or above permission to the whole "html" folder in this path :

> "/var/www/**html**/..."

Not just files and folders in it because i tried that completely.

Also apache:apache permission is not needed, root does the work.

This comment helped a lot:

[move_uploaded_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error?rq=1#comment79575689_8103860)